# XmlDocument.SelectNodes question

Tags: c#, .net, xml, xmldocument, selectnodes

What's the difference using root node to select and using document object to select nodes?
Which way is preferred.

For example,

1.

```
XmlDocument Doc = new XmlDocument();
Doc.Load(mem);

XmlNodeList nodeList = Doc.SelectNodes(@"//@id");
```

2.

```
XmlDocument Doc = new XmlDocument();
Doc.Load(mem);

XmlElement root = Doc.DocumentElement;

XmlNodeList nodeList = root.SelectNodes(@"//@id");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In fact, I never got any differences. And use just

```
Doc.SelectNodes(@"//@id");
```

because if document's root exists

```
bool b = Doc.OuterXml == Doc.DocumentElement.OuterXml; // true
```

Comment: Though the documentations suggests that if there is no root element, `Doc.DocumentElement` will return `null`, so the second listing on the OP may trow a `NullReferenceException`. I do agree with you, however.

Answer (score 1):

Since [XPath](http://www.w3schools.com/XPath/xpath_syntax.asp)'s `//` expression always matches from the document root, the result will be the same whether you start from the document root or from its `documentElement`.

So I guess you're better off using the shorter `Doc.SelectNodes("//@id");` syntax.

Comment: As far as if document's root exists `Doc.OuterXml = Doc.DocumentElement.OuterXml` I think any query will return the same result, XPath or any else

Comment: @abatishchev, not always. For instance, consider the document `<root><child /></root>` and the XPath expression `root`. That won't match anything if called from the document element.

Answer (score 1):

The root of an XML document contains its document element at least, but it may also contain processing instructions and comments.  For instance, in this XML document:

```
<!-- This is a child of the root -->
<document_element>
   <!-- This is a child of the document element -->
<document_element>
<!-- This is also a child of the root -->
```

the root has three child nodes, one of which is its top-level element.  In this case, this:

```
XmlNodeList comments = doc.SelectNodes("comment()");
```

and this:

```
XmlNodeList comments = doc.DocumentElement.SelectNodes("comment()");
```

return totally different results.